# pagination with 'no_found_rows' => true,

Tags: wp-query, pagination, mysql

I have 100000 records in my database and so many meta query performed on it so it takes lot of time to perform the operation, have checked few articles and using them it suggest disable no_rows_found using

```
'no_found_rows' => true,
```

How ever doing this stops pagination, is there any other way around to count records without this ?

below is the SQL which is generated via meta query:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'profe'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'magic' )
AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'country'
AND mt1.meta_value IN ('uae','uk','usa') )
AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'chargesof' ) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'magicposts'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY CAST(mt2.meta_value AS SIGNED) ASC
LIMIT 0, 12
```

Comment: You can't use the pagination parameters of `WP_Query` if you set `no_found_rows` to true. Without it `WP_Query` and the functions that rely on it have no idea how many pages there are or which page they're on. As an aside,I'd strongly recommend migrating from post meta to a taxonomy for some of that data. Taxonomies will be ***significantly faster***, and will give a massive performance boost to this kind of query. Anything that has to page through 10k records though should be a long running CLI task though

Comment: Hello tom there are so many attributes of post if I covert them to taxonomy it needs lot of taxonomy to be created. also what do you mean by cli task?

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem, you're swapping a row in the post meta table for a row in the terms table, a table designed for this kind of query. Moving to taxonomies would make your site _lighter_, not heavier. Any perception that taxonomies are hefty/weighty are inaccurate, it's querying for posts by their meta values that's expensive and heavy, afterall if it was cheap we'd store categories and tags as post meta. CLI/Command Line Interface. Browser requests are restricted by time and memory limits, CLI commands are not.

Comment: In particular, the post meta table is designed and indexed so that it's fast to find values when you already know the post ID. Taxonomy tables are optimised for the opposite, finding post IDs when you already know the value. Asking the database to find post IDs in the meta table is very expensive, and gets more expensive as the size of the table increases. That's why `get_post_meta` runs fast when you have lots of post, but a post meta query can bring down the server when several people visit a big site, but it's also why that meta query looks fine when you only have a handful of posts

Comment: Thanks tom for response